# time step from 0.1 second to half hour (30 minutes) with UTC decimal hours

Tags: r, data.table, xts

I have data at an interval of 0.1 second or 10 lines for one second
So 864000 lines for one day based on 24*60*60*10.

I want to find mean of columns (wind speed and other variables not shown here) in my data by aggregating it from 0.1 second time step to half hour. So data will be aggregated from 864000 lines to 48 lines (for one day)

Input:

```
           tms  Hr  Min Sec Wind speed
7/13/2014 0:00  0   0   0   3.45
7/13/2014 0:00  0   0   0.1 52.34
7/13/2014 0:00  0   0   0.2 1.23
7/13/2014 0:00  0   0   0.3 4.3
7/13/2014 0:00  0   0   0.4 1.34
7/13/2014 0:00  0   0   0.5 3.6
```

Output I want to see:

```
Year    Month   Day Hr  Wind speed
7/13/2014   7   13  0   21.92
7/13/2014   7   13  0.5 29.38
7/13/2014   7   13  1   24.18
7/13/2014   7   13  1.5 1.70
7/13/2014   7   13  2   1.80
```

My code for hourly mean and I want to change in to aggregate data by half hour (not one hour). Where `dat` is the data without `tms` column: so I added a date column.

```
library(data.table)
library(xts)
dat <- data.table(dat)
tms <- as.POSIXct(seq(0,24*(60*60*10)-1,by=1),origin="2014-07-13",tz="UTC")
xts.ts <- data.frame(xts(dat,tms))
```

Now I added `tms` column to my data

```
Aut <- data.frame(tms,xts.ts, check.names=FALSE, row.names=NULL) 
mean2 <- aggregate(Aut, 
                   list(hour=cut(as.POSIXct(Aut$tms), "hour")),
                   mean)
```

But this not correct even for hourly.  I want mean of my data by half hour. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want the output to be.  Aggregating by time is easy with xts, but you didn't provide reproducible input (`dat` isn't defined) or an example of the output you expect.  Provide those two things and you will probably receive several answers.

Comment: i edited it but probably it needs formatting

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich  I edited it and provided output but not sure what happened to the formatting. I want mean values from 0.1 second time step to 30 minutes(0.5 hour). so rolling down the data from 864000 lines to 48 lines for a day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you can do this easily with `xts::period.apply`:

```
library(xts)
options(digits.secs = 1)  # display fractional seconds
# create 1 day of timestamps that are 0.1 seconds apart
tms <- as.POSIXct(seq(0, 86400-1, by=0.1), origin="2014-07-13", tz="UTC")
# create an xts object with some random data and the times created above
set.seed(21)
xts.ts <- xts(runif(length(tms), 0, 50), tms)
# use period.apply and endpoints to calculate the 30-minute means
mean30min <- period.apply(xts.ts, endpoints(xts.ts, "mins", 30), mean)
# round up to next 30-minute period
mean30min <- align.time(mean30min, 60*30)
```

If you want the result to be a data.table or data.frame with the additional columns added, you can do that easily after aggregating.

```
library(data.table)
dt.mean30 <- as.data.table(mean30min)
dt.mean30[, Month := .indexmon(mean30min) + 1]
dt.mean30[, Day := .indexmday(mean30min)]
dt.mean30[, Hr := .indexhour(mean30min) + .indexmin(mean30min)/60]
```

Comment: @ Joshuha Thanks. when I applied period .apply "Error in endpoints(xts.ts, "min", 30) : unsupported "on" argument"    Also tms length should be 864000 (that I can try to fix)